# Addd Authorization to http endpoint in elsa workflow

Tags: elsa-workflows

I tried with token bearer and still api works without token.Is there any way how we can achieve Authorization in elsa workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Elsa 2.3 and below don't support HTTP Endpoint authorization. For that, you would need to update to Elsa 2.4.x (currently released as preview packages available from [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/gallery/elsa-2).

You will then see a new option that you can enable:

[image]

You can optionally specify a policy name to evaluate. If no policy is specified, the HTTP Endpoint will execute for any & all authenticated requests and reject anonymous requests.